Unable to generate CSV in Kibana when querying for an IP address
I'm trying to search for an IP address in my data on Elasticsearch (v8.8.0) using Kibana. If I simply enter the IP in Kibana's Discovery's query bar, and I try to export the results into CSV, I get an empty file and the error
Encountered an unknown error: Request timed out
Encountered an error with the number of CSV rows generated from the search: expected NaN, received 0

But if I query ip_of_interest: 1.1.1.1, i.e. specify which field I'm searching the IP on, I get the same results, and are able to export the results into CSV.
Why is there a difference in generating CSV when using different queries?
